# Calling Fragment method from Activity,findFragmentById returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to Fragments. I'm trying to develop swipe tabs.

I have the following Adapter:

```
public class HomeTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public HomeTabsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int idx) {
        switch (idx) {
        case CONSTS_MAIN.TAB_WATCH:
            return new WatchFragment();
        case CONSTS_MAIN.TAB_DISCOVER:
            return new DiscoverFragment();
        case CONSTS_MAIN.TAB_LOG:
            return new LogFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONSTS_MAIN.HOME_NO_OF_TABS;
    }

}
```

and MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
}
```

and of course, the Fragment classes:

```
public class WatchFragment extends Fragment {
public class DiscoverFragment extends Fragment {
public class LogFragment extends Fragment {
```

And basically everything seems to work fine graphically.

However, I'm trying to call method of the Fragment from the Activity. I'm doing it this way:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
WatchFragment watchFragment = (WatchFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.watch_fragment);
watchFragment.refresh();
```

and here `fm.findFragmentById` always return null.

I'm using `android.support.v4.app` all the way.

How can I get the Fragment class?

EDIT:

Here is the Fragment's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id ="@+id/watch_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_watch"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.x.y.custom_controls.CustomWatchChronologicalListView
        android:id="@+id/lvWatchChronologicalDiscussions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the Activity's layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Probably id you are using in `WatchFragment watchFragment = (WatchFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.watch_fragment);` is incorrect. Are you sure that `WatchFragment` is loaded into `R.id.watch_fragment`? Please check.

Comment: How do you handle fragments? Are you adding them dynamically or statically to the XML layout?

Comment: I added the layouts for both the Fragment and the Activity. @Rohit please take a look if something is not right with the Id.

Comment: @Marcin, I don't add the Fragment, I let the Adapter (HomeTabsPagerAdapter) take care of it. Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

In your adapter add a `SparseArray` to keep references to the fragments added

```
private final SparseArray<Fragment> mPageReferences = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
```

In your getItem method after instantiate the fragment add it to the array:

```
@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int idx)
{
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (idx)
    {
        case CONSTS_MAIN.TAB_WATCH:
            fragment = new WatchFragment();
        case CONSTS_MAIN.TAB_DISCOVER:
            fragment = new DiscoverFragment();
        case CONSTS_MAIN.TAB_LOG:
            fragment = new LogFragment();
    }
    if(fragment != null) {
        mPageReferences.put( position, fragment );
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

And add the followings methods:

```
@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        mPageReferences.remove(position);
    }

    public SherlockFragment getFragment(int key) {
        return mPageReferences.get(key);
    }
```

Finally you can get the fragment in the index you want like this:

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment)adapter.getFragment(index);
```

If you want to use keys to identify the fragments instead int index, you can use a `HashMap`

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do findFragmentById if your not defining the fragment using the fragment tag in xml.
Here you are passing id of a relative layout to the method findFragmentById.
The approach is to use the fragment instance you get from the fragmentMnager-

```
    WatchFragment watchFragment=(WatchFragment)getFragment(0);
    watchFragment.refresh(); 


    //getFragment Method
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragmentList=fragmentManager.getFragments();
 public   Fragment getFragment(int index){
        for (Fragment fragment:fragmentList){
            if (fragment.getId()==index)
                return fragment;
        }
    }
```